# It says I have the Outspoken badge, but I really don't

Tags: bug, status-completed

While perusing the moderator tools I noticed two little badge icons next to my name. The bronze one is for the Talkative badge which I do have. The silver one is for the Outspoken badge which I have not earned yet.

Obviously this is a minor issue but I figured I'd point it out.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, thanks for catching this. It will be deployed shortly.